# Why does '<,'> come up in Vim

Tags: vim, shortcut

Sometimes when I press : from normal mode, it starts with : ' < , ' >. Why does this happen and what is it good for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not in normal mode, but visual mode. When in visual mode every command starts with the visual mode range, `'<,'>`, automatically. This is useful if you want to run an ex command on your visually selected lines, e.g. `:s`, `:g`, and `:sort`. For more information see `:h v_:`.

Comment: Tips: Use `gv` (go visual) to re-select whatever you selected last.